# How set an hour with Calendar in scala

Tags: scala, calendar

I have the following code in scala:

```
import java.util.Calendar
var calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
var lastTimeProcessed = calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
```

In spark-shell, after creating lastTimeProcessed, appears like this variable is Unit, but what I want is initialized to 00:00.

This is the console result:

```
lastTimeProcessed: Unit = ()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You won't be able to get a formatted value "00:00" using one method call on the Calendar object.  We can  probably guess what you want but  you should search for examples with java.util.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat and then state the question more clearly.  Do you really just want the date formatted as a String?  That might not be the most useful form to use for filtering data (referring to your comment below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set of calendar returns void but it's does change the value of HOUR_OF_DAY or MINUTE based on this run:

```
scala> import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.Calendar

scala> var calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar: java.util.Calendar = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1474194792722,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Manila",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=10,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=39,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=262,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=18,MINUTE=33,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=722,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

scala> var lastTimeProcessed = calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
lastTimeProcessed: Unit = ()

scala> calendar
res0: java.util.Calendar = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Manila",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=10,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=39,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=262,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=33,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=722,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]

scala> calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)

scala> calendar
res2: java.util.Calendar = java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Manila",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=10,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=8,WEEK_OF_YEAR=39,WEEK_OF_MONTH=4,DAY_OF_MONTH=18,DAY_OF_YEAR=262,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=3,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=0,MINUTE=0,SECOND=12,MILLISECOND=722,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

An unsolicited advice, use joda time library.

Answer (score 1):

`set` is mutates the state of the instance and returns the `Unit` as output type.

State of the `calendar` has been changed. Now print the `calendar` to see the new mutated state.

```
calendar.getTime
```

Will show you the time after setting the `HOUR_OF_DAY`

```
 scala> calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
 res12: Int = 0
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how can get a variable from that, like 00:00? This is just for filtering data from, for example, 00:00 to 02:00